# Blackberry 10 | result::failure 500 invalid action install_2

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

For some reason after update my BB device up to 10.2.1.1057 version I got error during debugtoken.bar installation

> result::failure 500 invalid action install_2

What is the cause of this issue? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Technical details

The problem is in the way how `DDPB` utility try install the debug token. This utility try to install debug token application as usual blackberry application and sent `INSTALL` request (looks like it use `-installApp` param instead `-installDebugToken` param), you can see this information in output:

```
Info: Sending request: INSTALL
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 2645
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 2645 bytes
actual_dname::
actual_id::
actual_version::
result::failure 500 invalid action install_2
```

But the output should look like:

```
Info: Sending request: INSTALL_DEBUG_TOKEN
Info: Action: Install Debug Token
Info: File size: 2646
result::success
```

## Solution

Use [BB10 / PlayBook App manager plugin for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bb10-playbook-app-manager/kmbaalodpmjjhpobkgljnelbpblnikkp), it install debug tokens properly.

P.S. Also you can always install it via CLI utility `blackberry-deploy`

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the ant script to include the correct command:

```
<exec executable="${blackberry-deploy}" dir="." failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-installDebugToken" />
    <arg file="${properties.qnx.bbwp.dir}/debugtoken.bar" />
    <arg value="-device" />
    <arg value="${properties.qnx.device.ip}" />
    <arg value="-password" />
    <arg value="${properties.qnx.device.password}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use `gradle` as build system, and already have equivalent functionality. In any case, your code will be helpful for people who use ant